# What NEW features has WCF in .NET Framework 4 vs .NET Framework 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

What NEW features has WCF in .NET Framework 4 vs .NET Framework 3.5? What Is new, what was fixed (in general - I do not want to get into bug fixed numbers=)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would start with these links:

> - [Day 3 - What’s New in WCF 4](http://philippetruche.wordpress.com/2009/11/19/day-3-whats-new-in-wcf-4/)
> - [TechDays 2010 : What’s new in WCF 4](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/liese/TechDays-2010--Whats-new-in-WCF-4/)
> - [A Developer's Introduction to Windows Communication Foundation 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

Nicholas Allen has an "alternative" list of what's new features:

- Simplified configuration
- Standard endpoints
- IIS hosting without an SVC file
- Discovery
- Routing service (previously included with Dublin)
- REST caching and help page
- Workflow services
- Non-destructive queue receive
- Simple byte stream encoding
- ETW tracing

See: http://blogs.msdn.com/drnick/archive/2009/08/14/what-s-new-in-wcf-4-alternative-list.aspx

Those sum up quite nicely what's been improved.

Also Santosh Benjamin has a [blog post](http://santoshbenjamin.wordpress.com/2009/05/10/whats-new-in-wcf-4/) with links to a series of blog posts by Christian Weyer which extensively covers the new things in WCF 4.

Comment: what do you mean by "Simple byte stream encoding"?

Comment: I don't mean anything - this is Nicholas Allen's list of features :-) Check out Aaron Skonnard's article on MSDN (Andrew provided a link) - towards the end, there's a section on "ByteStreamMessageEncodingBindingElement" - that's probably what Nicholas Allen referred to

Answer (score 1):

MS.NET introduced many new features for C#.net 4.0,Asp.Net 4.0 and WCF. Please navigate the below links to read more about the features. New features of C#.NET 4.0 : http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/43540-C-NET-new-features.aspx
ASP.NET 4.0 Neaw Features:
http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/43538-New-features-ASP-NET.aspx